# What’s the lodash equivalent of this nested object creator function?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

So, I have this fuction that’s creating nested objects based on an array ok keys and I’m wondering how I could accomplish the same thing using lodash?

```
// nest
var nest = function (obj, keys, v) {
    if (keys.length === 1) {
        obj[keys[0]] = v;
    } else {
        var key = keys.shift();
        obj[key] = nest(typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' ? {} : obj[key], keys, v);
    }
    return obj;
}


// sample data
var keys = ['user','name','fullName'];
var value = 'John Smith';

// create nested object
var obj = {};
obj = nest(obj, keys, value);

// log out new nested object
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://lodash.com/docs#set

Comment: Ding ding ding!! That totally worked! (I'm just not too familiar with lodash, so thank you for the help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// include lodash somewhere...

// nest
var nest = function () {
    return _.set(obj, path, value);
}

// sample data
// var keys = ['user','name','fullName']; can use a path now!
var path = 'user.name.fullName';
var value = 'John Smith';

// create nested object
var obj = {};
obj = nest(obj, path, value);

// log out new nested object
console.log(obj);
```